# Windows Azure service mgmt API Swap issue

Tags: c#, api, azure, cloud, swap

I am relatively new to using the azure service mangemement API. I am trying to use the swap deployment operation but I keep getting an error that I am unable to fix. I may be going about this operation entirely wrong as I am new to azure. Any help is much appreciated.

The error I am getting is the following

```
<Error xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The resource service name hostedservices is not supported. If it is a new partner service please ensure that the service is registered in RDFE.</Message></Error>"
```

Here is my code, I have specified in it where the exception occurs

```
public void swapDeployment()
    {

        String operationName = "hostedservices";
        String prodName = "HealthMonitor - 21/10/2011 22:36:08";
        String sourceName = "SwapTestProject - 13/12/2011 22:23:20";

        Uri swapURI = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/"
                          + subscriptionId
                          + "/services/"
                          + "hostedservices"
                          + "/stevenRiordanHello/");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(swapURI);

        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2009-10-01");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";

        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Swap xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\"><Production>"+prodName+"/Production><SourceDeployment>"+sourceName+"</SourceDeployment></Swap>";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        try
        {
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e is CryptographicException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: The store is unreadable.");
            }
            else if (e is SecurityException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: You don't have the required permission.");
            }
            else if (e is ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid values in the store.");
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
        certStore.Close();

        if (0 == certCollection.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: No certificate found containing thumbprint " + thumbprint);
        }

        X509Certificate2 certificate = certCollection[0];

        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        try
        {
            //exception is caught at the end of the line below
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(WebException e)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream());
            string errorText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely because your service name has capital letters in it.  It should all be lower-case.  However, that being said... is there a reason you wouldn't just use the sample client instead of rolling your own HTTP client?

Updating this answer:  You have to have valid XML, but also the parameters to it are the deployment name.  This is one of those rarely used things.  It is typically a GUID.  The only way to really get this information is to use the [GetDeployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx) call or [GetHostedService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460806.aspx) call with details about the deployments.  In that response, you will see the name.  That name is definitely different than anything you supplied (I think you are using label).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i changed the service name to all lower case and i am still getting the same error. My code is based off code from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782.aspx which lists your hosted services.This code worked for me. But that code i know is for a GET, where as swap deployment operation is a POST.

Comment: Ok, is it then because of invalid XML? see:  "<Production>"+prodName+"/Production>"  Still... why don't you use cmdlets or sample client in csmanage?

Comment: Oh cheers for spotting that, but i am still getting the same error. And i am only a student and i dont actually know about "cmdlets or sample client in csmanage"

Comment: csmanage is here (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c) or use the cmdlets from here: http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/